# Forcing Strict Evaluation - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, seq

I want an intermediate result computed before generating the new one to get the benefit of memoization.

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import Data.List
parts' m = newmap
    where
    n = M.size m + 1 
    lists =  nub $ map sort $ 
        [n] : (concat $ map (\i -> map (i:) (M.findWithDefault [] (n-i) m)) [1..n])
    newmap = seq lists (M.insert n lists m)
```

But, then if I do

```
take 2000 (iterate parts' (M.fromList [(1,[[1]])]))
```

It still completes instantaneously.

(Can using an Array instead of a Map help?)

Comment: In what *"context"* is `take 2000` written? In the interactive shell?

Comment: I don't really see why you have to evaluate this strictly: you can still have memoization lazily: if you need key `400`, it will evaluate until it has found that element. It is possible it has done work in between. If you later need, `300` good chance, it is already evaluated. If you need element `600`, it can continue the work already carried out by evaluating `400` and `300`. Memoization and lazyness are not opposites.

Comment: Be wary of `deepseq`--it can easily make your program slow. A decent rule of thumb for single-threaded programs is that you should never `deepseq` anything large unless you absolutely need to. For parallel programs, you should typically `deepseq` large values only if doing so requires a lot of work per element. Remember: loading a value from memory into cache is expensive. If you dig through a data structure to force everything, and then go through it again to use it, you pay that cost twice. In many cases, you'll also burn a lot of extra time in garbage collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:**

If you need to **calculate the entire list/array/map/...** at once, you can use `deepseq` as @JoshuaRahm suggests, or the `($!!)` operator.

The answer below how you can enforce strictness, but **only on level-1** (it evaluates until it reaches a datastructure that may contain (remainders) of expression trees).

Furthermore the answer argues **why laziness and memoization are not (necessarily) opposites** of each other.

**More advanced:**

Haskell is a lazy language, it means it only *calculates* something, if it is absolutely necessary. An expression like:

```
take 2000 (iterate parts' (M.fromList [(1,[[1]])]))
```

is not evaluated immediately: Haskell simply stores that this has to be calculated later. Later if you really need the first, second, *i*-th, or the length of the list, it will evaluate it, and even then in a lazy fashion: if you need the first element, from the moment it has found the way to calculate that element, it will represent it as:

```
element : take 1999 (<some-expression>)
```

You can however force Haskell to evaluate something strictly with the [exclamation mark (`!`)](https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/Strictness), this is called *strictness*. For instance:

```
main = do
    return $! take 2000 (iterate parts' (M.fromList [(1,[[1]])]))
```

Or in case it is an argument, you can use it like:

```
f x !y !z = x+y+z
```

Here you force Haskell to evaluate `y` and `z` before "increasing the expression tree" as:

> *expression-for-x`+`expression-for-y`+`expression-for-z*.

**EDIT**: if you use it in a let pattern, you can [use the bang as well](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/StrictPragma):

```
let !foo = take 2000 (iterate parts' (M.fromList [(1,[[1]])])) in ...
```

---

Note that you only collapse the structure to the *first level*. Thus `let !foo` will more or less only evaluate up to `(_:_)`.

---

**Note**: note that *memoization* and *lazyness* are not necessary opposites of each other. Consider the list:

```
numbers :: [Integer]
numbers = 0:[i+(sum (genericTake i numbers))|i<-[1..]]
```

As you can see, calculating a number requires a large amount of computational effort. Numbers is represented like:

```
numbers ---> (0:[i+(sum (genericTake i numbers))|i<-[1..]])
```

if however, I evaluate `numbers!!1`, it will have to calculate the first element, it returns `1`; but the internal structure of `numbers` is evaluated as well. Now it looks like:

```
numbers (0:1:[i+(sum (genericTake i numbers))|i<-[2..]])
```

The computation `numbers!!1` thus will "help" future computations, because you will never have to recalcuate the second element in the list.

If you for instance calculate `numbers!!4000`, it will take a few seconds. Later if you calculate `numbers!!4001`, it will be calculated almost instantly. Simply because the work already done by `numbers!!4000` is *reused*.

Comment: I believe the `$!` in `return $! take 2000 (iterate parts' (M.fromList [(1,[[1]])]))` is entirely useless, because it only evaluates up to the topmost list constructor, and `take 2000 (iterate ... ...)` doesn't need to evaluate *any* of the `...` parts to find that the list is non-empty.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: true, that's why you need to perform "strictness" on every call level, such that the `i`-th element is forced to be evaluated as well...

Answer (score 4):

Arrays might be able to help, but you can also try taking advantage of the [deepseq](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq) library. So you can write code like this:

```
let x = take 2000 (iterate parts' (M.fromList [(1,[[1]])])) in do
     x `deepseq` print (x !! 5)    -- takes a *really* long time
     print (x !! 1999)             -- finishes instantly
```

Answer (score 4):

You are memoizing the partitions functions, but there are some drawbacks to your approach:

- you are only memoizing up to a specific value which you have to specify beforehand
- you need to call `nub` and `sort`

Here is an approach using `Data.Memocombinators`:

```
import Data.Memocombinators

parts = integral go
  where
    go k | k <= 0 = []  -- for safety
    go 1 = [[1]]
    go n = [[n]] ++ [ (a : p) | a <- [n-1,n-2..1], p <- parts (n-a), a >= head p ]
```

E.g.:

```
ghci> parts 4
[[4],[3,1],[2,2],[2,1,1],[1,1,1,1]]
```

This memoization is dynamic, so only the values you actually access will be memoized.

Note how it is constructed - `parts = integral go`, and `go` uses `parts` for any recursive calls. We use the `integral` combinator here because `parts` is a function of an Int.